# How to return a sub-array via array_filter

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

I want to create a function that searches among a large array and returns some fields , the array is for example like this ( `var_dump` of the large array ) :

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["group_id"]=>
    int(87)
    ["group_name"]=>
    string(28) "General Specifictaions"
    ["group_slug"]=>
    string(80) "%da%af%d8%b2%db%8c%d9%86%d9%87-%d9%87%d8%a7%db%8c-%d8%b9%d9%85%d9%88%d9%85%db%8c"
    ["group_desc"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["attributes"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["attr_id"]=>
        int(95)
        ["attr_name"]=>
        string(23) "Release date"
        ["attr_slug"]=>
        string(67) "%d8%aa%d8%a7%d8%b1%db%8c%d8%ae-%d8%a7%d9%86%d8%aa%d8%b4%d8%a7%d8%b1"
        ["attr_desc"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["value"]=>
        string(3) "144"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(5) {
        ["attr_id"]=>
        int(96)
        ["attr_name"]=>
        string(21) "Availability"
        ["attr_slug"]=>
        string(5) "stock"
        ["attr_desc"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["value"]=>
        string(7) "instock"
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["group_id"]=>
    int(89)
    ["group_name"]=>
    string(19) "Display"
    ["group_slug"]=>
    string(55) "%d8%b5%d9%81%d8%ad%d9%87-%d9%86%d9%85%d8%a7%db%8c%d8%b4"
    ["group_desc"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["attributes"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

This array is the list of all of the specifications of a product, what i want to do is to search for a specific attribute in `attributes` section and only return that attribute, and this search can be by `attr_id` or `attr_name` or `attr_slug` , so i created this function which uses `array_filter` but i can't return the part i want :

```
function dw_attr_value_by( $post_id = '', $field, $value ) {
    if( !$post_id ){
        global $post;
        $post_id = $post->ID;
    }

    if( !$post_id ) return;

    $table = dw_get_table_result( $post_id ); // The large array

    return array_filter( $table, function( $v, $k ) use( $field, $value ){
        $attributes = $v['attributes'];

        if( sizeof( $attributes ) == 0 ) return;

        for( $i = 0; $i < sizeof( $attributes ); $i++ ) {
            if( $field == 'id' ) {
                if( $attributes[$i]['attr_id'] == $value ) break;
            } elseif( $field == 'slug' ){
                if( $attributes[$i]['attr_slug'] == rawurlencode( $value ) ) break;
            } elseif( $field == 'name' ){
                if( $attributes[$i]['attr_name'] == $value ) break;
            }
        }

        return $attributes[$i];

    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH );
}
```

It does filter the array but it doesn't return the part i want , for example i want the result to be like `var_dump( dw_attr_value_by( $post->ID, 'id', 144 )` :

```
array(5) {
    ["attr_id"]=>
    int(95)
    ["attr_name"]=>
    string(23) "Release date"
    ["attr_slug"]=>
    string(67) "%d8%aa%d8%a7%d8%b1%db%8c%d8%ae-%d8%a7%d9%86%d8%aa%d8%b4%d8%a7%d8%b1"
    ["attr_desc"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["value"]=>
    string(3) "144"
}
```

JSON-formatted of the large array

```
[{"group_id":87,"group_name":"\u06af\u0632\u06cc\u0646\u0647 \u0647\u0627\u06cc \u0639\u0645\u0648\u0645\u06cc","group_slug":"%da%af%d8%b2%db%8c%d9%86%d9%87-%d9%87%d8%a7%db%8c-%d8%b9%d9%85%d9%88%d9%85%db%8c","group_desc":"","attributes":[{"attr_id":95,"attr_name":"\u062a\u0627\u0631\u06cc\u062e \u0627\u0646\u062a\u0634\u0627\u0631","attr_slug":"%d8%aa%d8%a7%d8%b1%db%8c%d8%ae-%d8%a7%d9%86%d8%aa%d8%b4%d8%a7%d8%b1","attr_desc":"","value":"144"},{"attr_id":96,"attr_name":"\u0648\u0636\u0639\u06cc\u062a \u0628\u0627\u0632\u0627\u0631","attr_slug":"stock","attr_desc":"","value":"instock"},{"attr_id":99,"attr_name":"\u0628\u0644\u0648\u062a\u0648\u062b","attr_slug":"%d8%a8%d9%84%d9%88%d8%aa%d9%88%d8%ab","attr_desc":"","value":"yes"},{"attr_id":100,"attr_name":"\u0648\u0627\u06cc \u0641\u0627\u06cc","attr_slug":"%d9%88%d8%a7%db%8c-%d9%81%d8%a7%db%8c","attr_desc":"","value":"no"}]},{"group_id":89,"group_name":"\u0635\u0641\u062d\u0647 \u0646\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634","group_slug":"%d8%b5%d9%81%d8%ad%d9%87-%d9%86%d9%85%d8%a7%db%8c%d8%b4","group_desc":"","attributes":[]},{"group_id":57,"group_name":"\u067e\u0631\u062f\u0627\u0632\u0646\u062f\u0647","group_slug":"%d9%be%d8%b1%d8%af%d8%a7%d8%b2%d9%86%d8%af%d9%87","group_desc":"","attributes":[]}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that array_filter is a proper way to do that. However you just need to create a variable out of callback function and save filtered data there.

```
$foundAttrs = [];
$filteredArray = array_filter( $table, function( $v, $k ) use( $field, $value, $foundAttrs){
    $attributes = $v['attributes'];

    if( sizeof( $attributes ) == 0 ) return;

    for( $i = 0; $i < sizeof( $attributes ); $i++ ) {
        if( $field == 'id' ) {
            if( $attributes[$i]['attr_id'] == $value ) break;
        } elseif( $field == 'slug' ){
            if( $attributes[$i]['attr_slug'] == rawurlencode( $value ) ) break;
        } elseif( $field == 'name' ){
            if( $attributes[$i]['attr_name'] == $value ) break;
        }
    }
    array_push($foundAttrs, $attributes[$i]);

    return $attributes[$i];

}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH );

//now $foundAttrs consists of all found values
```

If you post origin array(e.g. json string) it will be easier to come up with better idea, because now it is not easy to test possible solution

**UPDATE**

Firstly a few words about the code posted in question:

1. if you count something inside 'for' statement (I mean `sizeof($attributes)`) the loop does that command
   on every iteration
2. `return $attributes[$i];` will simply return the last element of $attributes if all IF/ELSE statements fail

So I fixed these points and rewrote the function with help of foreach loops. If it doesn't work, please post the given array(the large one) as a json string so I will be able to test my solution with real data

```
function dw_attr_value_by( $post_id = '', $field, $value ) {
    if( !$post_id ){
        global $post;
        $post_id = $post->ID;
    }

    if( !$post_id ) return;

    $table = dw_get_table_result( $post_id ); // The large array

    foreach($table as $groupKey => $group) {
        if (isset($group['attributes'])) {
            foreach ($group['attributes'] as $attr) {
                if( $field == 'id' && $attr['attr_id'] == $value) {
                    return $attr;
                } elseif( $field == 'slug' && $attr['attr_slug'] == rawurlencode($value)){
                    return $attr;
                } elseif( $field == 'name' && $attr['attr_name'] == $value){
                    return $attr;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but is there a more proper way, i would appreciate it if you give me a clue.